# Persisting fetched data React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobx

I am working on a mini social network in React Native. From the feed page, users can navigate to the comments page for any given post. The only problem is, when navigating back, the feed page re-renders, making the user lose the current position on the newsfeed. How do I make the feed screen render only once (on app start), then re-render if the user refreshes? (I use the FlatList component).

P.S.: Any state management library's methods are welcome (MobX, Redux or setStates)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you can make with Redux or MobX. You just need to have a flag variable to true on some reducer, when the feed request ends change it to false and then on the Feed component on every componentDidMount you need to compare the variable if its true you make the request (when the user opens the app) if its false you do nothing.